# UITableView hierarchy is not in a single line

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a simple table view with cells. When I run the app in simulator and checking the hierarchy it is not aligned in single line, instead it is looking as nested.

UI Design as below:
[image]

Hierarchy looks as below:
[image]

It looks fine in other view controller, please check below image:
[image]

My concern is table view cells are not aligned in single line. But for other table views cells are on the same line, check 3rd image.

Can someone please help how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: What problem are you concerned with?

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableView` does a ***lot*** of work "behind the scenes."

One big task is managing efficient display of its cells - remember, cells are *reused*.

As you begin using the table view, cells are added. As you scroll, *some* more cells will be added... but then they start to be reused.

Note also that the **scroll indicator** view is part of the hierarchy!

So, depending on cell heights (and, I'm sure, many other factors) the table view *may* add 3 cells, then add the scroll indicator view, then add 2 more cells - giving you a "staggered" hierarchy.

As you continue to scroll, the table *may* (almost certainly ***will***) rearrange the order of the cells. So each time you use Debug View Hierarchy the cells "level" in the hierarchy can (will) change.

This is completely normal, and, unless we're doing something with the cells that we probably should not be doing, will have no adverse effect.